# Every students' score plus their group score in Excel power pivot

Tags: microsoft-excel, pivot-table, power-query, powerpivot

There are students' scores based on their usual performance (scoreName), and group scores based on their group performance (scoreGroup). The total scores equal to their 'scoreName' plus their own group scores 'scoreGroup'. How to get everyone's total scores ('Result' as figure 1)? I have put the two tables into Pivot table and built relationship as figure 2, but don't know how to operate further. Thanks!

The excel file can be downloaded [here](https://1drv.ms/f/s!Ail2QiXX3I2JgYNCzVh_aKyGU0mFcA?e=hUmRmK)

Figure 1

[image]

Figure 2

[image]

Comment: Can you provide a sample of the source data table

Comment: @Brian, Have upload, thanks!

Comment: Are you set on doing this via a PivotTable or are you open to an alternate solution? I have a partial PivotTable solution but I have a solution I believe to be more elegant.

Comment: @Brian, Thanks, can you provide your better solution?  I have a lot of data to deal in this format, but the data in the sample is only a small part.

Comment: Let me describe my solution before I create a tutorial. First, I would select, copy, and paste all the names into a new location. Second, I would eliminate duplicates. Third, using an array calculation, I would pull the matching group numbers for each name. Fourth, I would use pull the individual scores using an array formula (and the array formula could sum, average, etc.). Fifth, I would pull the matching group scores using another array formula. Lastly, the two columns with the individual and group scores could be combined. Would this layout achieve your ultimate goal?

Comment: @Brian, Thank you for your solution, can you provide the Excel file? Additionally, I am concerned that if the data volume is too large, will the operational efficiency be too low due to formula reasons?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution [file](https://1drv.ms/x/s!An8h_gKrTGYPr98USTJngHZwuzaggw?e=CBm5Iq). Note, that in order to use array formulas, you must press `ctrl+shfit+enter` simultaneously.

1. First, I would select, copy, and paste all the names into a new location.
2. Second, I would eliminate duplicates.
3. Third, using an array calculation, I would pull the matching group numbers for each name.
4. Fourth, I would use pull the individual scores using an array formula (and the array formula could sum, average, etc.).
5. Fifth, I would pull the matching group scores using another array formula.

[image]

- I2: `=MIN(IF($B$2:$B$7=H2,$A$2:$A$7))`
- J2: `=AVERAGE(IF($B$2:$B$7=H2,$C$2:$C$7))`
- K2: `=SUM(IF($E$2:$E$3=I2,$F$2:$F$3))`